Seeking name of method for interpreting reality of phenomena as only a result or emanation of a more meaningful higher system/agent
I have noticed that a method of interpreting evidence according to a higher system/agent is important to some theology and philosophy - for example, Plato's theory of forms used to interpret material forms, Christianity's demonology to used to interpret spiritual experiences, Marx's theories of social structure used to interpret human behaviour, Perennialist's theories of universal wisdom used to interpret spiritual traditions.
My interest in finding the term for this method is related to the method of ontological reductionism being used to dismiss the perceived reality of a phenomena. The unnamed method is related because it can be perceived as performing a similar dismissal, but inverted: instead of questioning the reality of a phenomena by inferring that it is only the constituents that have meaning, it questions the reality of phenomena by inferring that it is a only result or emanation of a more meaningful higher system/agent.
Is there a name for this method of interpretation? Otherwise, what are similar methods to that being described?
Edit: Another way of putting it would be, if reductionist theories can produce emergent phenomena, what if causation could be entirely top-down? I found the term demergence which refers to a singular emergent phenomena that can affect its multiple parts, but what of a non-emergent singular cause that has downward causation and produces a variety of phenomena? What is such a method named?

You give different examples where a specific theory claims to explain a bunch of related phenomena. That's the usual way of understanding on the basis of a theoretical explanation.

I agree, but I intentionally didn't include reductionist theories such as La Mettrie's theory of biological machinery to explain human consciousness. Those theories attempt to show how a multiplicity of lower/smaller causes produce a higher/greater singular phenomena. My examples attempt to show cases where an allegedly higher/greater singular cause determines a multiplicity of lower/smaller phenomena. So if the former is reductionist, what is the latter?

Heidegger's theme is that beings come from Being, e.g. <<What shines into beings, though can never be explained on the basis of beings nor constructed out of beings, is Being itself [Das in das Seiende Hereinscheinende, jedoch aus dem Seienden nie Erklärbare oder gar Machbare ist das Sein selbst].>> Parmenides, 106, GA 54 157. (quote c/o T Huyen)

@ChrisDegnen Could you please give a precise reference to the quote from Parmenides. There exist 19 fragments of Parmenides, named B1-B19. Thanks.

Examples are too heterogeneous to suggest a common "method". Emanationism is more specific and does not cover either Christianity or Marx. If anything, Marx's social "superstructure" is derivative of material "base". The opposite of reductionism is holism, wholes have properties over and above those of their components, but it is broader. "Hidden reality" esotericism is close, but it is a mixture of disparate "methods".

@Conifold I generally agree, thank you. If the concept of downward causation within Emanationism is split from the rest of the philosophy, I think it covers my heterogenous examples. I also agree on Marx, it is not a pure example, however, the superstructure can exert downward causation on the base and this is what I was interested in. I realise now I need to specify non-emergent downward causes. Holism does emphasise non-reductionism, but is silent on if holist phenomena is a result or emanation of higher causes.

"Emanation" does not fit as broadly as you are looking for. In monotheism and Oriental doctrines, "higher causes" do not emanate phenomenal reality, they are transcendent to it and 'descending' is not an aspect of their nature. Christians describe the relationship as "creation" and contrast it to emanation. Downward causation as such need not have any mystical aspect to classify such causes as "higher". Marx's "downward causation" is just a feedback effect entirely compatible with reductionism. Reductionists do not reduce wholes to sums of parts in the first place, there are also interactions.

@JoWehler Via Google Books

@Conifold Thank you for clarifying, I now realise I may have been conflating creation with emanation. With that in mind I will have to re-research Christian demonology. You've given me a few other legitimate reasons to doubt my question's coherence/answerability, I'll see if I can tighten the logic or if the whole thing falls apart. Is it appropriate to leave this question "up" when even I am unsure if it is answerable?
